# MacOS: Reduce CPU usage for VNFaceObservation

Tags: swift, macos, vision-api

I'm trying to detect faces on the webcam feed with Vision API.
The CPU usage is very high, like 60% or 80%. Is there any way to reduce it?

I've tried receding the frames per second which I pass from the webcam feed. However that didn't help.
Here's how I am trying to detect faces. This has to be updated in real time.

```
try? VNSequenceRequestHandler().perform([VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()], on: image)
if let results = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest().results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // update UI
    }
}
```

Comment: try to reduce size and width and height of  applying image

Answer (score 2):

**Vision**

- Try defining a `regionOfInterest` in `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest`
- Verify that your request "*[…] request is free to leverage the GPU to accelerate its processing.*" with the `usesCPUOnly` property
- If your usage permit it try `preferBackgroundProcessing`

**AVFoundation**

Also you can choose a lower quality for your capture devices if your are using `AVCapture`

Like choosing the right settings based on `ProcessInfo.processInfo.thermalState` :

- 'AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset'
- Analysing a max number of face per secondes
- Disabling HDR if is not need for your `AVCaptureDevice`

**Other**

- Reduce the number of update of your `CVPixelBuffer`

  - Allocating a fixed size of it
  - If you display it for the user, only use the displayed part
- If you're doing some post image processing consider using `Accelerate`

> Avoid as much work on the main thread